# DropDown Error AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('brandPortalApp');

app.directive('dropdownMultiselect', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{           
            model: '=',
            options: '=',
            pre_selected: '=preSelected'
        },
        template: "<div class='btn-group' data-ng-class='{open: open}'>"+
        "<button class='btn btn-small'>Select</button>"+
        "<button class='btn btn-small dropdown-toggle' data-ng-click='open=!open;openDropdown()'><span class='caret'></span></button>"+
        "<ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu'>" + 
        "<li><a data-ng-click='selectAll();'> Check All<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i> </a></li>" +
        "<li><a data-ng-click='deselectAll();'> Uncheck All<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i> </a></li>" +                    
        "<li class='divider'></li>" +
        "<li data-ng-repeat='option in options'> <a data-ng-click='setSelectedItem()'>{{option.value}}<span data-ng-class='isChecked(option.value)'></span></a></li>" +                                        
        "</ul>" +
        "</div>" ,
        link: function(scope){

            scope.openDropdown = function(){        
                scope.selected_items = [];
                for(var i=0; i<scope.pre_selected.length; i++){                        
                    scope.selected_items.push(scope.pre_selected[i].value);
                }      

            };

            scope.selectAll = function () {
                scope.model = _.pluck(scope.options, 'value');
            };            
            scope.deselectAll = function() {
                scope.model=[];
            };
            scope.close = function() {
                scope.dropdown=false; 
            };
            scope.setSelectedItem = function(){
                var id = this.option.value;
                if (_.contains(scope.model, value)) {
                    scope.model = _.without(scope.model, value);
                } else {
                    scope.model.push(value);
                }
                return false;
            };
            scope.isChecked = function (value) {                 
                if (_.contains(scope.model, value)) {
                    return 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok';
                }
                return false;
            };                                 
        }
    } 
});
```

This is the directive I have defined for MultiSelectDropDown, But I am getting an error saying pre_selected is not defined in openDropdown () function. But it is already defined.Should I add or define somewhere for the error to go? Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Post a complete example reproducing the error, and post the exact and complete error message.

Comment: Do you pass the `pre-selected` to your directive? e.g. `<dropdown-multiselect pre-selected="someVar">`

Comment: @JBNizet Error msg  looks like      TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at m.scope.openDropdown (AddPricePromotionCtrl.js:27)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14539), <anonymous>:4:520)
    at b (angular.js:15628)
    at e (angular.js:25172)
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17378)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:17478)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:25177)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: That shoud be in the question, as well as the complete minimal example reproducing the error.